# How to install armhf on ubuntu

Tags: arm

How to install `armhf` in ubuntu 18.04 and why is this command not working

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture armhf
```

Comment: please add the results of `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures` into the question.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason for it not to work.

> 2.1.1. Supported Architectures
>
> [Ubuntu 18.04 supports](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/s390x/ch02s01.html) six major architectures and several variations of each architecture known as “flavors”. One other architecture (IBM/Motorola PowerPC) has an unofficial port.
>
> ```
> Architecture  Ubuntu Designation
> - Intel x86-based     i386         
> - AMD64 & Intel 64    amd64        
> - ARM with hardware FPU   armhf 
> - 64bit ARM   arm64        
> - IBM POWER Systems   ppc64el     
> - IBM z/Architecture  s390x
> ```

The command, as is traditional in Linux, does not show any output.

```
$ dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
i386
$ sudo dpkg --add-architecture armhf
$ dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
i386
armhf
```